# Loading data from database in select option html - Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, laravel

Hello I have issue with my jquery code, because when I want to press any key to get query from database that is not working (it is not showing any alert). I think my ajax isn't working very well because I tried to copy other code and didn't work. I want to get data from database with my skills to choose in  options

jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#skills").click(function () {
      alert("test")
    });
  });
```

---

```
<select class="select2bs4" multiple="multiple" name="ums[]" data-placeholder="Skills"
                style="width: 100%;" id="skills">
</select>
```

And I want to do when I press any key then should show any result in multiple select but at beginning didn't show any alert yet.

I tried to do like "Select2 and Laravel: Ajax Autocomplete" from Laraget website and that wasn't working too

EDIT____
If it's only input with type 'text' it's working fine to show alert

Thank you in advance

Comment: you don't `click` a select tag, right??you `change` it.  select tag supports event `change` not `click`. so your alert is not triggering. change the event from `click` to `change`.

Comment: The [select element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#See_also) does not fire a click event - only 'change' and 'input' so your jQuery will not get triggered.   Can you explain more what you are trying to achieve? Where is the user typing clicking to fill this box?

Comment: I want to user show user skills to choose after type some character. This skills gonna show from database with AJAX but at beginning I want to test this 'change' or 'keyup' functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select will not work with click but with change , but if you want change when you write in select like search bar , replace this :

```
$("#skills").click(function () {
  alert("test")
});
```

to this if you want to get the change option :

```
$("#skills").on('change',function () {
  alert("test")
});
```

or this if you want to handle user input :

```
$("#skills").on('keyup',function () {
  alert("test")
});
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, I have no result (because I did not load database) but I want press some keys for example scrum and when I press for example 's' and then 'c' I want to show me result from database but now I'm testing and If I click 's' then nothing happens, no alert, no anythink

Comment: same, nothing. IMO I'm doing something wrong but IDK what. At laraget website this is working (but full demo), maybe should I try this do full. But If keyup isn't sending any event so that will not work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#skills").change(function () {
       alert("test")
    });
});
```

Comment: Please mak as verified this answer if its help for you Thank you @pastersky Happy coding :)